# Delphi: TFlowPanel margins between each control

Tags: delphi, controls, margin, flowpanel

I am using the TFlowPanel and at runtime i am creating a variable number of controls (in this example TButton) on it.
I want to create a margin between each control, but it doesnt work yet.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  LButton: TButton;
begin
  for i := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    LButton := TButton.Create(flwpnl1); // flwpnl1 is the TFlowPanel
    LButton.Parent  := flwpnl1;
    LButton.Height  := 20;
    LButton.Caption := Format('Status%d', [i]);
    LButton.Margins.Left   := 20;
    LButton.Margins.Top    := 20;
    LButton.Margins.Right  := 20;
    LButton.Margins.Bottom := 20;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Example]

Any ideas why?

Regards and thanks,
Dennis

Comment: `LButton.AlignWithMargins:=True;`?

Comment: Shame on me! Of course... That worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wonder if this is possible with the TFlowPanel because not all controls have AlignWithMargins property. For instance, adding TImage.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set AlignWithMargins to true, so in your code that would be:

```
LButton.AlignWithMargins := true;
```